# Assigning Variables for Programmatic Examples in Rspec

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I am setting up some automated tests using Rspec and Selenium and I am running into some issues trying to create my examples programmatically.

I have an array with multiple items which need to be tested multiple times based on changes to the data.

The array:

```
def get_array
  @stuff = { thing1, thing2, thing3 }
end
```

Simplified version of the tests:

```
describe "My tests" do
  context "First round" do
    before { #do some stuff }

    @my_array = get_array
    @my_array.each do |k|
      it "should pass the test" do
        k.should pass_the_test
      end
    end
  end

  context "Second round" do
    before { #do some other stuff }

    @my_array = get_array
    @my_array.each do |k|
      it "should pass the test" do
        k.should pass_the_test
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It's not too bad in this example, but having to call @my_array = get_array each time is definitely not DRY. As I am adding more tests and complexity, this is quickly getting out of hand, so I am wondering what is the easier/better way to do this that I am missing.

I have tried shared contexts and anything else I could find, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment, @benny-bates, I realized that the problem wasn't the before block but just initializing the variable before calling the tests. Unfortunately it looks like turning your instance variable into a constant is probably the best way to go.

```
describe "My tests" do

  STUFF = {thing1, thing2, thing3}

  context "First round" do
    before { #do some stuff }

    STUFF.each do |k|
      it "should pass the test" do
        k.should pass_the_test
      end
    end
  end

  context "Second round" do
    before { #do some other stuff }

    STUFF.each do |k|
      it "should pass the test" do
        k.should pass_the_test
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Geoff. That was one of the things I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It will work if @stuff is used from within the it block, but not if it is used before the block. In that case I get: "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" on the "@stuff.each do" line

Comment: Thanks again @geoff-petrie, but still getting the same error: "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" which tells me that the array is nil. Another example which I think matches your answer but returns that error is here: https://gist.github.com/benbates/5096712

Comment: Thanks for the gist, @benny_bates. I see your issue now. Part of the challenge for me is that the tests are a little different than I'm used to seeing. Testing through an iteration with RSpec seems to require what you're already doing. That said, if you change `@stuff` to a constant `STUFF` you'll get the results you want.

Comment: Nice. I hadn't even thought about using it as a constant. Not sure if it is best practice, but I think I could vastly simplify things if I change some stuff around and try this route out. If you want to edit/update your answer I'll be happy to accept it as the only way to possibly do what I am trying to do.  Thanks!

Comment: one other quick question. It actually seems to work using a global variable as well. Any harm/benefit using one or the other, aside from not changing constants?

Comment: The trouble with working with globals is that they can potentially permeate your codebase. I don't have any direct experience with using them in anything significant, though, as I tend to shy away from them. [This link](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html) has some brief words on the matter, though. I've also updated my answer to address the use of a constant.